# What is the best way to send vibration sensor timeseries data through FIWARE Orion Context Broker?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cosmos

I am relatively new in FIWARE and I was looking for some directions.

We are interested in using FIWARE for timeseries sensor data collection. Since vibration data is a bit intense unlike a temp. sensor, we would like to send viration data in ***batches*** with certain time periods e.g. every 5 mins one second of data window in batches. Is it possible to send data in such way as a vector for example through Context Broker with a target to persist in a timeseries database? (e.g. CrateDB)

Could you please give me some hints or point me to the resources that  ?

Answer (score 0):

Both Orion and the NGSI-LD brokers (Orion-LD, Scorpio, and Stellio) support batches of entities - an array of entities for creation, update and/or upsert. So, that's not a problem, just pick the broker you like the most!
Orion doesn't store the historical data in its DB, just the current state, but, if you need the history, just connect a Cygnus, or Quantum Leap, or ... to Orion, and make it subscribe to what you need in the history and that takes care of it. About Crate/timescale ... you'll have to take a look inside the [FIWARE Catalogue](https://www.fiware.org/developers/catalogue/), and read a little about the GEs to find out which GE support what you need - you find all of them inside "Core Context Management".

The NGSI-LD brokers support the temporal data natively and no other GE is needed. Of the three, Scorpio (written in Java) is the most mature, but if you need performance, you will probably have to go with Orion-LD (written in C).

Good Luck!